# Multiplying functions together in Python

Tags: python-3.x, function, lambda, multiplication

I am using Python at the moment and I have a function that I need to multiply against itself for different constants.

e.g. If I have `f(x,y)= x^2y+a`, where 'a' is some constant (possibly list of constants).

If 'a' is a list (of unknown size as it depends on the input), then if we say `a = [1,3,7]` the operation I want to do is

```
(x^2y+1)*(x^2y+3)*(x^2y+7)
```

but generalised to n elements in 'a'. Is there an easy way to do this in Python as I can't think of a decent way around this problem? If the size in 'a' was fixed then it would seem much easier as I could just define the functions separately and then multiply them together in a new function, but since the size isn't fixed this approach isn't suitable. Does anyone have a way around this?

Comment: Make sure you read through this if you're new (and welcome!) https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Usually you post your attempted code along with your question (meaning you try to help yourself before asking others to help you). This should be achievable by a simple function but maybe I am missing something, perhaps if you post your attempted code it will clarify what you are asking. Python allows you to return multiple values if that' what you're after?

Comment: you shouldn't care if the size is fixed or not, this is what loops are for

Comment: I have posted my code below, which doesn't quite work. Am I even going about it the right way or would you suggest to do a different approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can numpy ftw, it's fairly easy to get into.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,3,7])
x = 10
y = 0.2
print(x ** (2*y) + a)
print(np.sum(x**(2*y)+a))
```

Output:

```
[3.51188643 5.51188643 9.51188643]
18.53565929452874
```

Comment: Should have clarified that the answer can't be in floats as it needs to be integrated afterwards using dblquad. Check my code below (which is wrong as it doesn't do what I need it to do), it would be great if you could comment on whether this is the correct approach to do or I should be trying a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really got much for it to be honest, I'm still trying to figure out how to get the functions to not overlap.

```
a=[1,3,7]

for i in range(0,len(a)-1):
    def f(x,y):
        return (x**2)*y+a[i]
    def g(x,y):
        return (x**2)*y+a[i+1]
    def h(x,y):
        return f(x,y)*g(x,y)
f1= lambda y, x: h(x,y)
integrate.dblquad(f1, 0, 2, lambda x: 1, lambda x: 10)
```

I should have clarified that the end result can't be in floats as it needs to be integrated afterwards using dblquad.